# How to make gnome terminal to display all the contents of standard output?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to display all the ouput of a command in the gnome terminal(not minimum or less output).

For example while i run `dpkg --get-selections` command, it displays only the partital output on terminal.But i want the whole list of installed packages.

What i have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the right way and just use `less`. Just enter:

```
dpkg --get-selections | less
```

And use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to scroll down and up respectively through the output.

Comment: Arrow and paging keys also work.